# В чем проблема? При любом числе в консоле выходит 0

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Универ. Вложенные циклы

```
int main()
{
    int t, k, i;
    cout << "k = ";
    cin >> k;
    double p = 0, s;
    for(t=1;t<=k;t++)
        if (t != 3) {
            s = 1;
            for (i = 1; i <= t; i++)
                if (i != 7)
                    s *= (i + 2) / (i - 7);
            p *= sin(t) / (t - 3);
        }
    cout << "s = " << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**При вводе любого числа выводит 0 или -0**

Comment: А если считывать из консоли число - оно автоматом будет числом? Или надо преобразовать строку в число?

Comment: автоматом должно, насколько знаю

Comment: Как минимум, тут - `s *= (i + 2) / (i - 7);` - неверное целочисленное деление. И все же, что у вас планируется делать при `i == 7`? Надо просто пропустить этот член? А при `t == 3`?

Comment: [Как отлаживать маленькие программы](https://habr.com/ru/post/339038/)

Comment: Главная глупость -

    `double p = 0;`

После этого что ни считайте - `p *= sin(t) / (t - 3);` - `p` обнулится. Правда, вы зачем-то выводите `s` :)

Comment: Поймите, наш преподаватель сказал что мол правильно всё. Когда же всё иначе.

Comment: Пригласите преподавателя в этот вопрос на SO.

Answer (score 1):

> Поймите, наш преподаватель сказал что мол правильно всё. Когда же всё иначе.

Если преподаватель сказал, что все верно - кто мы такие, чтоб спорить с авторитетом?

Только непонятно, какой ответ вы хотите услышать? Если вы его уже сформулировали...

Если бы студентом был я, я бы написал так, даже без оптимизации суммы:

```
double series(int k)
{
    double p = 1;
    for(int t = 1; t <= k; ++t)
        if (t == 3) continue; else
        {
            double s = 0;
            for(int i = 1; i <= t; ++i)
                if (i == 7) continue; else s += (i+2.)/(i-7.);
            p *= sin(t)/(t-3)*s;
        }
    return p;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for(int k = 1; k < 10; ++k)
        cout << setw(2) << k << " "
             << setw(10) << series(k) << endl;
}
```

Но, понятно, это ответ не для вас - у вас же все по словам препода верно, а для кого-то другого, OK?

Comment: извините, не хотел никого оскорблять. хотел просто понять где собственно ошибка.

Comment: Одну я вам изложил. Произведение инициализируется не нулем, а единицей. Вторую тоже - у вас деление целочисленное. Третья - вы вместо суммы считаете произведение. Четвертая - в ваше произведение `p` сумма не включается... Словом, проще оказалось написать с нуля, чем исправлять.

Comment: Спасибо огромное буду разбираться.